# How to show complete record in vf page and use javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a requirement to add javascript pop-up validation to a custom object and not use validation. I am thinking that if I just show the record in a vf page I can add javascript to it.

Is it possible to have show a record with it's standard layout in a vf page but at the same time add javascript checking? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: This plan sounds like it will generate a lot of technical debt really quickly. If you do go down this path and the validations are critical, you should also add them on the server side as well.

Comment: I am told that they just want to give a pop up asking if the user checked a checkbox is sure or not and inform them what happens if they continue. Would you still use backend for this?

Comment: If that's all it is, have you considered using a custom button on a standard page layout? (Click a button instead of check a checkbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use visualforce tag `<apex:detail>` to show the record with its standard layout.

Just few lines of code and complete record will be shown,

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
   <apex:detail subject="{!account.ownerId}" relatedList="false" title="false"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Check [standard documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_detail.htm) for more details

Comment: How to do this for a custom object? This doesn't work <apex:page Controller="Proposal__c">
   <apex:detail subject="{!Proposal__c.Id}" relatedList="false" title="false"/> 
</apex:page>

Comment: @ApexN-u-b Even though it's a custom object, you still want to use the `StandardController` attribute on the page tag.

Comment: `<apex:page StandardController="Proposal__c"> `

Comment: Whoops. I don't see data. https://cs18.salesforce.com/apex/GRANt_proposal_w_Javascript_vf?a0711000007VYmk

Comment: furthermore, how to set it up that when a user clicks a record in a listview it shows it in this page?

Comment: You would have to override the view page. Which is under Buttons, Links, and Actions